# Relative clauses: "I did the best I could."

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, superlative-degree, noun-phrases

> I did the best I could.

The sentence above can be rephrased:

- I did the best that I could.

In these two examples *(that) I could* is a relative clause. However, I am not sure whether it is modifying *best* or *the best* or an ellipted element. What exactly is this clause modifying?

Secondly, what type of phrase is *the best* here and what type of word is *best*?

Comment: Nifty question! --whole lotta shakin goin on there. My stab: *could* is a 'coded' *could do*. *Best* might be taken as an adverb, the superlative grade of *well*; but here I think it's an adjective so-to-speak 'fused' with its (dummy( head and thus recategorized as a noun, required because E *do* in its 'pro-verbal' sense requires an object, even if that's a dummy. And *the* is elicited/licensed (you pays your money and you takes your choice) by the restrictive relative clause.

Comment: @StoneyB Oh, I so wish I understood all of that!

Comment: **the best** is a fused head noun phrase. And hence the relative clause  is simply modifying a NP.

Comment: @Man_From_India So, if *the best* is an NP here, where is the corresponding gap in the relative clause? Hmmm

Comment: @Araucaria hmmm I see it this way -  *I did [the best] (that) I could (do) ____* In the gap it has to be *the best* as in *I could do the best*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't answer OP's question, but it addresses the confusion another answerer here has.

He said in his answer *"**best** is a noun in **I did the best I could**, but an adjective in **I did the best thing I could**"*.

I strongly oppose that conclusion. In my opinion **best** is an adjective both in **I did the best I could** and in **I did the best thing I could**.

Here are the reasons -

- A noun can't be modified by an adverb (A noun phrase can, but we are talking about only noun not the noun phrase). An adjective, however, can be pre-modified by an adverb like *very*.

> This time they cared enough to serve the very poor.

See in the sentence above **poor**, though, seems like a noun. But it's actually not. How *poor*? *very*. The adverb *very* pre-modifies an adjective. So *poor* is not a noun.

> She is the most beautiful of them.

Here *beautiful* is not a noun. *most beautiful* is the superlative form of the adjective *beautiful*.

Similarly, in OP's quoted sentence *best* is an adjective.

---

**ANSWER TO OP -**

> I did the best (that) I could (do).

The mention of *do* here is optional. Similarly optional is the mention of relativizer in the relative construction - *(that) I could (do)*.

The antecedent here is the noun phrase (NP) - **the best**.

Now it's a different type of noun phrase where the head of the noun phrase is fused with its internal modifiers. Such NPs are called **Fused-head NP**.

> I did [**the best**] [*(that)* I could *(do)* ___].

Comment: Now, I understand why you are confused and mistaken. 1. The word *very* could function as an [adjective](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/very). Just because a word could be modified by "very" doesn't mean the following word is an adjective. In "that's the **very** point I want to make", **point** is not an adjective. 2. Whether an adverb can modify a noun or noun phrase is controversial. I don't want to get into that. However, I don't think it has anything to do with classifying **best** as a noun or adjective.

Comment: @Rathony you are actually right. I overlooked it completely. That **very** in my quoted sentences are all *adjectives*. Let me think of it a little more.

Comment: Either you or the OP or both might want to take a look at my new question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/446569/superlative-relative-clause

Answer (score 3):

A few omissions in the sentence:

> I did the best (thing or things) (that) I could (do).

1. "Thing" is omitted because it is not necessary. The noun [*best*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/best) itself can mean "the best thing". Therefore, we could say the relative clause is modifying its antecedent  *the best*.
2. If you don't omit the noun *thing (s)*, "best" will be the superlative form of the adjective *good*. Otherwise, "the best" is a noun phrase functioning both as an object of the transitive verb to *do* and an antecedent of the relative clause.

Comment: Good answer but it's worth pointing out that "the best" could mean "the best *things*" as well as "the best thing" in this context.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I stand corrected. Are you happy with the edit?

Comment: If it could be "things" understood, then why couldn't we say in the passive, *"The best I could do were done."?

Comment: "I did the best [thing[s]] [that] I could [do] ____."

Comment: It's very strange that without **thing** *best* is a noun and with **thing**, *best* is a superlative adjective.

Comment: @Man_From_India I've been with you all the way. But *best* is still an adjective/adverb, every which way you look at it. "The best" might be a noun phrase, but "best" isn't a noun!

Comment: @Man_From_India Btw, your grammar has moved forward frighteningly fast! I'm very impressed ... . I'm absolutely certain that there are *many* things I could learn from you now. I look forward to lots of interesting chats :)

Comment: @Araucaria That is exaggeration :P if anything you FE snail stoney DT and many more here helped me a lot with my grammar. And still I'm learning. Thanks :)

Comment: @Man_From_India Yes, we've all helped each other, I hope :) Your grammar is spot on (as much as any of our grammar is spot on). It's a real pleasure to read your comments.

Comment: @Man_From_India Are you saying that best is not superlative in "the best thing"?

Comment: @Rathony you got me wrong. What I meant is *best* is an adjectives both in *the best* and *the best thing*.

Comment: @Man_From_India What makes you think it is not a noun? What difference does it make? Do you mean "best" doesn't have a definition for a noun?

Comment: @Rathony I wish I could write an answer. But due to my lack of time and some other issues I can't sit down and write it. But there are plenty of reasons not to consider it a noun. (previously I was like you. I always checked dictionaries for their POS, but that's actually not a good practice. Initially this is hard to believe, but actually it's not.)