# What part of speech is "the closest" in this case?

Tags: parts-of-speech, relative-clauses

> What is **the closest** you've ever come to losing your life?

（From : https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-closest-youve-ever-come-to-losing-your-life）

Apparently, it comes from the construction "come close to doing" , so "the closest" should be an adverb (in superlative degree) . But relative clauses cannot modify  an adverb.（I follow the CGEL by Quirk et al.）

Someone would view it as a NP where the noun has been omitted(the closest situation). But this analysis is also flawed, because a NP cannot fit in the relative clause that follows.

Is there a better idea ？

Comment: Related: [relative clauses_I did the best I could](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329006/relative-clauses-i-did-the-best-i-could).

Comment: Relative clauses can modify superlative adverbs, which is what's happening here. Note that "the" modifies "closest".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a preposition have the form of superlative?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96118/can-a-preposition-have-the-form-of-superlative) ('nearest' rather than 'closest' is examined)